# How to do a full text search in Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, full-text-search, lucene

I need something like Lucene to do an optimized full text search in Cocoa. I am working on an Iphone app to search through a database.

Anybody has any luck with other databases. Any help is appreciated.

So far, I can only find this.

http://github.com/tcurdt/lucenekit/tree/master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment:
"..I am not sure if I explained myself properly. I am looking to build an Iphone app that can do searches by passing the search phrases to a remote server..."

You could just use the Java (or .NET) version of Lucene server side and pass the search query to the server from the phone in objective c

Answer (score 1):

The official Lucene is written based on Java, if I'm not mistaken, and I haven't played with the ObjC port you've mentioned.  It's a Mac OS X project and a quick look shows some dependancies that may be difficult to port over to the iPhone.

Depending on the complexity of your searching needs I see a few possible paths for you:

1. For simple searching: the built-in SQLite supports indexes.  This will be fast.
2. Wait for SDK 3.0 and CoreData.
3. Try your luck porting the above project.

Comment: looks like SQLLite is an easy way out. I am not sure if I explained myself properly. I am looking to build an Iphone app that can do searches by passing the search phrases to a remote server. Can this be done using standard architecture?